# Showing/hiding status bar causes view to jump

Tags: swift2

I have an app that has a few views that are presented modally on the screen. I would like to hide the status bar (or show the modal overtop of the status bar) however when I use:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

it works however when I dismiss the view and go back to the previous one, the view seems to jump back in to place with the status bar shown.

Any solution to showing a modal view on top of the status bar?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read in Apple Documentation,

UIViewController Class Reference

By setting modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance property to YES, you specify the presented view controller controls status bar appearance, even though presented non-fullscreen.

```
destinationViewController.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true;
```

Try this in your code, since you have not shared the complete project, its difficult to give exact changes required.

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

I hope it helps.